# C++ Code that runs in CLion IDE but not on Leetcode.com

Tags: c++

```
// Leetcode Version
class Solution {
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

public:
    int romanToInt(string s) {
        char symbol[7] = {'I','V','X','L','C','D','M'};
        int value[7]   = { 1 , 5 , 10, 50,100,500,1000};
        int int_ = 0;
        int temp = 0;

        for (int i; i < s.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
                if (symbol[j] == s[i]) {
                    temp = j;
                }
            }

            if (s[i+1] == symbol[temp + 1]) {
                int_ = int_ + (value[temp + 1] - value[temp]);
                i++;
            }

            else if (s[i+1] == symbol[temp + 2]) {
                int_ = int_ + (value[temp + 2] - value[temp]);
                i++;
            }

            else {
                int_ = int_ + value[temp];
            }
        }

    return int_;
    }
};
```

I'm fairly new to C++ and trying to improve by doing a question on LeetCode.com every day. Today I've been working on this [Roman to Integer problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/roman-to-integer/). I was able to get the code to run just fine using CLion, but for the life of me, I can not figure out how to get it to run on Leetcode.com. I feel like I must be missing the smallest thing.

It always tells me the output is zero. But bizarrely, if I leave in this line of code from my CLion version right below the function call ...

```
int romanToInt(string s) {
 std::string a;
 std::cout << "Please enter a roman numeral: ";
 std::cin >> a;
```

It will say my code is accepted when I run it. But when I actually submit it, I get this error:

```
Line 506: Char 9: runtime error: pointer index expression with base 0x000000000000 overflowed to 0xffffffffffffffff (basic_string.h)
```

I understand the basic idea of overflow as a concept but don't know how to pinpoint where it occurs here.
Any help in understanding these issues will be greatly appreciated! 
And for comparison, here's the code that works perfectly in my IDE, CLion:

```
// CLion Version
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "MMMCMXCIX";
    //std::cout << "Please enter a roman numeral: ";
    //std::cin >> s;

    char symbol[7] = {'I','V','X','L','C','D','M'};
    int value[7]   = { 1 , 5 , 10, 50,100,500,1000};
    int int_ = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i; i < s.length(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (symbol[j] == s[i]) {
                temp = j;
            }
        }

        if (s[i+1] == symbol[temp + 1]) {
            int_ = int_ + (value[temp + 1] - value[temp]);
            i++;
        }
        else if (s[i+1] == symbol[temp + 2]) {
            int_ = int_ + (value[temp + 2] - value[temp]);
            i++;
        }
        else {
            int_ = int_ + value[temp];
        }
    }

    std::cout << int_;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at how you index the string and the arrays and consider what the largest index that you might be using is, especially when you use `+1` as in `s[i+1]` and `symbol[temp + 1]` and so on. Then compare that to the size of these strings/arrays. Do you see a problem? If you index an array or string out-of-bounds, then your program has *undefined behavior* and there is no guarantee that it will do the correct thing.

Comment: Think what will happen in case of last run of the loop -> s[i+1]. This will point to outof bound of an array.

Comment: Thank you both for insightful comments.